# Frequent audio takes too much CPU - JavaFX

Tags: javafx, optimization, audio

I'm trying to develop a tower defense in JavaFX. My game runs fine, even with many turrets and enemies, but when I start using sound effects for tower shooting, performance drops after a short while significantly. I've tried  using different methods.

```
public void shotSound() {
        this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this.hit);
        this.mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1);
        this.mediaPlayer.play();
        this.mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
            this.mediaPlayer.stop();
        });
    }
```

This is the method for the sound effect. I have even tried adjusting the duration of the audio but to no avail, it is still lagging (cpu usage skyrockets when using audio for my turrets and increases by time to the point that the game becomes unplayable). So I'm asking if there is a better way to play a frequent sound than by doing this, the audio file is shorter than the execution of shooting, of course. My turrets fire 4 times in 1 second, the length of my audio file is around 100ms so it shouldn't be a problem.

Am I missing something? Will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: `MediaPlayer` is the wrong tool for this. Use [`AudioClip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html). And you don't have to create a new `AudioClip` every time. Just call `play()` on a stored instance when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing a new `MediaPlayer` with every shot is an enormous inefficiency. As @Slaw says in the comment, `AudioClip` is a much better choice. Just make sure you set up your sounds ahead of time: don't initialize the `AudioClip` every time you wish to play it.

An important bonus with `AudioClip` is that you can call it multiple times, playing the sound concurrently. This is a great advantage if the situation is to provide a cue for a gun shot or laser blast in a battle. Also, `AudioClip` lets you play back at different frequencies, so you can play the same sound effect at slightly different speeds to simulate many different weapons going off, all with a single cue held in memory.

The Java `Clip` is similar to the `AudioClip` in that the sound is held in memory, and can be replayed. But it doesn't support concurrent playback or playback at different pitches. I wrote a small library called `AudioCue` that does allow concurrent plays and has real time panning and pitch changes and also includes a listener that can trigger when a sound ends. But it only supports 16-bit 44100fps wav files. I made a little [comparison chart of four different clip-like options](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue#comparison-of-clip-alternatives).